# topic-tag-sitemap.xml redirects to 404 page

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-code-404, sitemap

I'm using WordPress SEO by Yoast to improve to improve our on-page SEO. But I got a problem with the **topic-tag-sitemap.xml**. It redirects to the 404 (Page not found) site. All the other sitemaps work very well.

I hope someone could help me with this and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be not be the answer your looking for however topic tags are normally not something that you want search engines to index.  Most SEO experts (I would include myself) recommend that you be very careful with topic tags and even avoid them completely.

Here's some good reading on topic tags.  Maybe you'll change your mind on submitting the sitemap and then you won't have to worry about it:

http://moz.com/blog/setup-wordpress-for-seo-success